# Optimizing cartesian product between two Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes with the same columns:

**Dataframe 1**:

```
          attr_1  attr_77 ... attr_8
userID                              
John      1.2501  2.4196  ... 1.7610
Charles   0.0000  1.0618  ... 1.4813
Genarito  2.7037  4.6707  ... 5.3583
Mark      9.2775  6.7638  ... 6.0071
```

**Dataframe 2**:

```
          attr_1  attr_77 ... attr_8
petID                              
Firulais  1.2501  2.4196  ... 1.7610
Connie    0.0000  1.0618  ... 1.4813
PopCorn   2.7037  4.6707  ... 5.3583
```

I want to generate a correlation and p-value dataframe of all posible combinations, this would be the result:

```
   userId   petID      Correlation    p-value
0  John     Firulais   0.091447       1.222927e-02
1  John     Connie     0.101687       5.313359e-03
2  John     PopCorn    0.178965       8.103919e-07
3  Charles  Firulais   -0.078460      3.167896e-02
```

**The problem is that the cartesian product generates more than 3 million tuples. Taking minutes to finish**. This is my code, I've written two alternatives:

First of all, **initial DataFrames**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'userID': ['John', 'Charles', 'Genarito', 'Mark'],
    'attr_1': [1.2501, 0.0, 2.7037, 9.2775],
    'attr_77': [2.4196, 1.0618, 4.6707, 6.7638],
    'attr_8': [1.7610, 1.4813, 5.3583, 6.0071]
}).set_index('userID')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'petID': ['Firulais', 'Connie', 'PopCorn'],
    'attr_1': [1.2501, 0.0, 2.7037],
    'attr_77': [2.4196, 1.0618, 4.6707],
    'attr_8': [1.7610, 1.4813, 5.3583]
}).set_index('petID')
```

**Option 1**:

```
# Pre-allocate space
df1_keys = df1.index
res_row_count = len(df1_keys) * df2.values.shape[0]
genes = np.empty(res_row_count, dtype='object')
mature_mirnas = np.empty(res_row_count, dtype='object')
coff = np.empty(res_row_count)
p_value = np.empty(res_row_count)

i = 0
for df1_key in df1_keys:
    df1_values = df1.loc[df1_key, :].values
    for df2_key in df2.index:
        df2_values = df2.loc[df2_key, :]
        pearson_res = pearsonr(df1_values, df2_values)

        users[i] = df1_key
        pets[i] = df2_key
        coff[i] = pearson_res[0]
        p_value[i] = pearson_res[1]
        i += 1

# After loop, creates the resulting Dataframe
return pd.DataFrame(data={
    'userID': users,
    'petID': pets,
    'Correlation': coff,
    'p-value': p_value
})
```

**Option 2 <strike>(slower)</strike>**, from [here](https://www.mkonrad.net/2016/04/16/cross-join-cartesian-product-between-pandas-dataframes.html):

```
# Makes a merge between all the tuples
def df_crossjoin(df1_file_path, df2_file_path):
    df1, df2 = prepare_df(df1_file_path, df2_file_path)

    df1['_tmpkey'] = 1
    df2['_tmpkey'] = 1

    res = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='_tmpkey').drop('_tmpkey', axis=1)
    res.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df1.index, df2.index))

    df1.drop('_tmpkey', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df2.drop('_tmpkey', axis=1, inplace=True)

    return res

# Computes Pearson Coefficient for all the tuples
def compute_pearson(row):
    values = np.split(row.values, 2)
    return pearsonr(values[0], values[1])

result = df_crossjoin(mrna_file, mirna_file).apply(compute_pearson, axis=1)
```

Is there a faster way to solve such a problem with Pandas? Or I'll have no more option than parallelize the iterations?

### Edit:

As the size of the dataframe increases **the second option results in a better runtime**, but It's still taking seconds to finish.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is well formulated, only thing that's missing is two dataframes with `pd.DataFrame` so we can instantely run the code and get same result as you. Right now your columns are truncated so the problem is not reproducable.

Comment: You probably want something like: `df1.corrwith(df2, axis = 1)` but data will help

Comment: Thank you for your interest! The source is a huge CSV with technical information. I edited the question to add a reproducible example

Comment: What part is slower in Option 2: `df_crossjoin` or `compute_pearson`?

Comment: I'm not totally sure. Perhaps making a Cross Join and then a linear operation like `apply` makes thing (naturally) slower than computing the entire dataset only once. As Pandas doesn't parallelize, the loop implementation is a viable alternative

Comment: Nope. I was wrong. I'm trying with differents Dataframe sizes and when they're bigger the second option results in a better computing time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of all the alternatives tested, the one that gave me the best results was the following:

1. An iteration product was made with
   [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).
2. All the iterations on both *iterrows* were performed on a Pool of
   parallel processes (using a [map](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) function).

To give it a little more performance, the function `compute_row_cython` was compiled with [Cython](https://cython.org/) as it is advised in [this section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#enhancing-performance) of the Pandas documentation:

In the `cython_modules.pyx` file:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import numpy as np

def compute_row_cython(row):
    (df1_key, df1_values), (df2_key, df2_values) = row
    cdef (double, double) pearsonr_res = pearsonr(df1_values.values, df2_values.values)
    return df1_key, df2_key, pearsonr_res[0], pearsonr_res[1]
```

Then I set up the `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name='Compiled Pearson',
      ext_modules=cythonize("cython_modules.pyx")
```

Finally I compiled it with: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

The **final code** was left, then:

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing
from cython_modules import compute_row_cython

NUM_CORES = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_CORES)
# Calls to Cython function defined in cython_modules.pyx
res = zip(*pool.map(compute_row_cython, itertools.product(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows()))
pool.close()
end_values = list(res)
pool.join()
```

Neither Dask, nor the `merge` function with the `apply` used gave me better results. Not even optimizing the apply with Cython. In fact, this alternative with those two methods gave me memory error, when implementing the solution with Dask I had to generate several partitions, which degraded the performance as it had to perform many I/O operations.

The solution with Dask can be found in my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59865572/dask-running-out-of-memory-even-with-chunks/).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another method using same cross join but using the built in pandas method [`DataFrame.corrwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) and [`scipy.stats.ttest_ind`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html). Since we use less "loopy" implementation, this should perform better.

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

mrg = df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop(columns='key')

x = mrg.filter(like='_x').rename(columns=lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[0])
y = mrg.filter(like='_y').rename(columns=lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[0])

df = mrg[['userID', 'petID']].join(x.corrwith(y, axis=1).rename('Correlation'))

df['p_value'] = ttest_ind(x, y, axis=1)[1]
```

```
      userID     petID  Correlation   p_value
0       John  Firulais     1.000000  1.000000
1       John    Connie     0.641240  0.158341
2       John   PopCorn     0.661040  0.048041
3    Charles  Firulais     0.641240  0.158341
4    Charles    Connie     1.000000  1.000000
5    Charles   PopCorn     0.999660  0.020211
6   Genarito  Firulais     0.661040  0.048041
7   Genarito    Connie     0.999660  0.020211
8   Genarito   PopCorn     1.000000  1.000000
9       Mark  Firulais    -0.682794  0.006080
10      Mark    Connie    -0.998462  0.003865
11      Mark   PopCorn    -0.999569  0.070639
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly It's throwing an error: `None of [Index(['geneID', 'petID'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]`

Comment: Check your column names in the `mrg` dataframe.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake. I've edited the question, I forgot to set the index. `userID` and `petID` are index, not columns. Don't worry, I'll try to figure out how to adapt your code to this particular case. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunatelly with a Cross Join between 2 dataframes of 100 rows each this is the slower alternative: Option 1 -> 3.4234 secs. Option 2 -> 2.3864. This option -> 9.8907. Thank you anyway!